# OS X + Crontab: How do you run SCP via cron?

Tags: macos, bash, cron, scp

This works fine when I run it by hand:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
/usr/bin/scp me@server:~/file ./
exit 0
```

However, when the cron runs the file is never touched. I know the ssh keys are right - replace that `scp` with an `ssh` and it runs fine.

Comment: I would recommend specifying the full path to `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`, just as you have for `scp`. It's good security practice, if nothing else.

Comment: What kind of `scp` command is that? At least one of the arguments should follow the pattern `user@host:path` or `host:path`.

Comment: My bad, overlooked that when simplifying the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron generally is run as root, have you tested this script as root to ensure that the ssh keys are in the correct location that root looks for?  Or do you have your sshkeys in your user profile?

Comment: I was under the impression that they ran as the user, but I was wrong! Using sudo to generate the key and pushing that one fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You also might consider using rsync for this process instead of scp'ing the file as a cron script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version you are running, but in Snow Leopard cron jobs run as the user (check with `whoami` in your cron'd script) ... at least when the user is currently logged in.